# Can't get python packages to work correctly

Tags: python, import, package, directory-structure

So I am having trouble getting the packages in python to work correctly. I have the following directory setup:

- TestPackages(Project Name, or parent directory)

  - MyPackage

    - _init__.py
    - CustomClass.py
  - OuterClass.py

The contents of each class is below:

**__init__.py**

`from CustomClass import CustomClass`

**CustomClass.py**

```
class CustomClass:
     def __init__(self):
         print("im a custom class")
```

**OuterClass.py**

```
from MyPackage import CustomClass
print("im the outer class")
cc = CustomClass()
```

I believe this is the proper way to do it from a website that showed me how. I'm new to Python and I'm aware this is a simple problem but I can't seem to get it to work. Pycharm  says there are errors in the `__init__.py` class and says it can't find the `CustomClass`.

What am I doing wrong and how do I properly set up the directory stucture?

**Note:** running Python 3.5.1

Comment: check this  short video , may help you :http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3wtite_python-tutorial-chapter-12-modules_tech

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?  This is critical.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Python 3.5.1, forget to add that

Comment: You don't need `__init__.py` in Python 3, and you can just move `CustomClass` directly into `MyPackage.py` and remove the directory `MyPackage`.  You do need to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to point to your `TestPackages` path.

Comment: @JohnZwinck But what if I were to want the `MyPackage` directory in order to organize the file structure. I'm pretty familiar with Java and am trying to replicate a form of the package system that Java has in Python. I'm trying to avoid having one giant single directory of all the `.py` files and would like some form of organization and structure